# SharePoint PDF document check-in issue with Adobe Reader

Tags: 2013, document-library, error, pdf, check-in

I am working on SharePoint 2013.

I am not able to check-in PDF documents through Adobe Reader for only one library. I am able to check-in documents in other libraries.

I am getting below error:

> Could not update metadata on the server. Please check your network connections or contact the server administrator.

Library settings are similar to other library settings.

Comment: Is there a Required field that needs a value in it?  You can check via Document Library settings.

Comment: Yes. There is a required  field. As I Cannot modified the existing Library so I created Library form the list template and uploaded the PDF document in new Library I am able to Check-in the PDF through Abode Reader.

Comment: I found the Issue. When I Compared the Document Properties from two libraries document in adobe. There is a extra column is coming which was not in columns and content type that is causing the issue. I need to find out from where extra column is coming.